# Find all prime $x$ such that $x^2+2$ is a prime

Tags: number-theory

I have tried fermats little theorem with fail. I cannot see how to proceed with this problem, find all prime $x$ such that $x^2+2$ is a prime.

Comment: $x=3$ is obvious; I think the next step is to consider the outcomes $\mod 3$...

Answer (score 5):

Elaborating on [abiessu's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524400/find-all-prime-x-such-that-x22-is-a-prime#comment3104190_1524400).

Suppose that $x = 3$. Then $x^2+2 = 11$.

Now, suppose that $x > 3$. In particular, now $3$ does not divide $x$. Then $x = 1 \mod 3$ or $x = 2 \mod 3$. Then $x^2 = 1 \mod 3$ and $x^2 + 2 = 0 \mod 3$, that is, $3$ divides $x^2+2$, so $x^2+2$ cannot be prime.

Answer (score 0):

Every prime larger than 3 has the form $x=6k\pm1$. Putting this into $x^2+2$ we obtain $$36k^2\pm 12k+3$$ which is evidently a multiple of 3.